# suitescript userevent beforesubmit

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

i'm tying to get  record form item fullfilment

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 *@author test 
*/
    define(['N/record'],
        function(record){
            function beforeSubmit(context){
                var currRec = context.newRecord;
                
            var currRec = record.submitField({
                        type: record.Type.itemfulfillment,
                        id: currRec.getValue('custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment'),
                        values: {
                            custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment: currRec.getValue('custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment')
                        },
                /*options:{
                    enableSourcing: false,
                    ignoreMandatoryFields: true
                }*/

            });
            
            }
return{
beforeSubmit:beforeSubmit
            };
        });
```

but when I run there is an error like this

```
TypeError: Cannot find function submitField in object [object Object].
```

how to solve this error. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but, it should be `record.submitFields` not `record.submitField`.

Also take note, the return of that function is the internal ID of the record **NOT** the actual record.

Comment: I trying and this my typo thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is because submitField isnt a function that is available in that module. If you want to update a field on a record you can use the "setValue" function of the "Record" object to set the value of a field and then call the "save" function to save the changes to the record. Like this:

```
currRec.setValue({
fieldId: "custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment",
value: currRec.getValue("custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment"),
});

currRec.save();
```

Comment: I've tried updating. but, still with the same error 
`define(['N/record'],
function(record){
function beforeSubmit(context){
var currRec = context.newRecord;

record.submitField({
type: record.Type.itemfulfillment,
id: currRec.getValue('custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment'),
values: {
custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment: currRec.getValue('custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment')
},
});
currRec.setValue({
fieldId:'custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment',
value: currRec.getValue('custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment'),
});
currRec.save();
}`

Comment: You are using record.Type.itemfulfillment, but it should be record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT (capitalization matters). Also: The id parameter should be the internal ID of the item fulfillment record, not the value of the custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment field. ```currRec.setValue({
  fieldId: 'custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment',
  value: '2022-12-27'
});

currRec.save();```

Comment: i'm sorry, can you show me about the full script that. Thanks...

Comment: ```/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 *@author test
 */
define(["N/record"], function (record) {
  function beforeSubmit(context) {
    // Get the current record
    var currRec = context.newRecord;

    // Update the custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment field with a new value
    currRec.setValue({
      fieldId: "custbody_me_f_date_item_fulfillment",
      value: "2022-12-27",
    });

    // Save the changes to the record
    currRec.save();
  }

  return {
    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
  };
});```